# Qt Plugin with OpenMP Support on MinGW: Undefined reference?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, cmake, openmp

I am developing a "Qt Plugin" which uses OpenMP (OpenMP support can be enabled/disabled using CMake parameter). I use MinGW  and CMake as development environment.
This is how I enable/disable OpenMP in the code:

```
#ifdef OPENMP_ENABLE
#pragma omp parallel for
#endif  for(int i=0; i<volumeData->getZSize(); i++){  .
```

I have enabled OpenMP in CMake file as follows:

```
OPTION (OPENMP_SUPPORT  "Build with OpenMP parallaization enabled")

IF (OPENMP_SUPPORT)
 FIND_PACKAGE( OpenMP )
 SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")

 IF ( OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS )
  MESSAGE("------- Adding compiler parameter for OpenMP")
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DOPENMP_ENABLE)
 ENDIF()
ENDIF()
```

and to build Qt plugin, I have configured CMake as follows:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_PLUGIN)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_SHARED)
```

This configuration compiles fine with Linux.
In Windows it compiles fine WITHOUT OpenMP support.
But when build with OpenMP support, it gives the error

> c:/mingw4/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   warning:auto-importing has been
>   activated without --enable-auto-import
>   specified on the　command line. This
>   should work unless it involves
>   constant data structures referencing
>   symbol from auto-imported DLLs.
>   CMakeFiles\RinzoDLPluginIPThreshold.dir\ui\dialogthresholdconfig.cpp.obj:C:/svnosaka3d/trunk/osaka3d/rinzo-platform/src/dlplugins/imageprocplugins/thresholdPlgin/ui/dialogthresholdconfig.cpp:221:
>   undefined reference to
>   `GOMP_parallel_stat'
>   CMakeFiles\RinzoDLPluginIPThreshold.dir\ui\dialogthresholdconfig.cpp.obj:C:/svnosaka3d/trunk/osaka3d/rinzo-platform/src/dlplugins/imageprocplugins/thresholdPlgin/ui/dialogthresholdconfig.cpp:221:
>   undefined reference to`
>   GOMP_parallel_end
>
> CMakeFiles\RinzoDLPluginIPThreshold.dir\ui\dialogthresholdconfig.cpp.obj:
>   In function
>   `ZN21DialogThresholdConfig9slotApplyEv.omp_fn.0':
>   C:/svn/osaka3d/trunk/osaka3d/rinzo-platform/src/dlplugins/imageprocplugins/threholdPlugin/ui/dialogthresholdconfig.cpp:223:
>   undefined reference to`
>   omp_get_nu_threads'
>   C:/svn/osaka3d/trunk/osaka3d/rinzo-platform/src/dlplugins/imageprocplugins/threholdPlugin/ui/dialogthresholdconfig.cpp:223:
>   undefined reference to
>   `omp_get_thead_num'
>   C:/svn/osaka3d/trunk/osaka3d/rinzo-platform/src/dlplugins/imageprocplugins/threholdPlugin/ui/dialogthresholdconfig.cpp:233:
>   undefined reference to`
>   omp_get_thead_num' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make[2]: ***
>   [dist/plugins/libRinzoDLPluginIPThreshold.dll]
>   Error 1

Here is my complete CMake file:
http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/view.php?id=2552392&da=y

Any tip?

Comment: The link to the complete CMake file requires registration.  Can you replace it with a publicly accessible site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenMP requires a runtime library (called `libgomp` in case of gcc), which must be linked into the created executable.  It is therefore not sufficient to add the OpenMP flags to the compilation flags, they must also be added to the link flags:

```
set_target_properties(<target_name> LINK_FLAGS "${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Of course, you need to replace `<target_name>` with the actual name of your target.

And by the way, and extra definition like `OPENMP_ENABLE` is superfluous.  If OpenMP is enabled, the macro `_OPENMP` is implicitly defined to contain the supported version of OpenMP (more precisely, the release date of the supported standard).  You can use this macro to test for OpenMP support in the source code:

```
#if defined(_OPENMP)
// use openmp
#endif
```